# mydots and linewrapping,

Tags: spacing, macros

Can someone help me improve upon this command?

```
\def\mydots{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox to 0.40em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill\kern0pt}
```

I have been using his to fill space between raggedright and ragged left words. However I have begun to use in environments with small horizontal widths (which require line-wrapping) and it begins to break.

The following was created using:

```
\begin{itemize}
        \item First Line \mydots \textit{10 km}
        \item Second line \mydots \textit{20 meters}
        \item Another entry \mydots \textit{10 dollars}
        \item Some longer distance$^1$ \mydots \textit{20 goals}
        \item Time for parentheses (+1L) \mydots \textit{20 liters}
        \item Time for zero parenthesees \mydots \textit{20 liters}
        \item Time for a really lengthy sentence \mydots \textit{40 euros}
        \item Now-hyphened sentence \mydots \textit{10 doors}
        \item Now-hyphened but really long sentence \mydots \textit{20 points}
        \item another short \mydots \textit{5 verses}
        \item Last one for now$^1$ \mydots \textit{30 days}\\ \rule{0 pt}{0in}$^1$\textit{Sample footnote causing no known issue}
\end{itemize}
```

[image: Example of wrapping problems]
As you can see my standard use case is some text followed by `\mydots` followed by some italic text (but not always, I am looking to make this work under any situation). My difficulty is that I hope to improve this command without modifying its implementation, its part of my .cls and would require manual change of hundreds of files.

Essentially what I want to happen is that all the text following \mydots needs to be forced into one line, linebreaking the pre-\mydots text wherever needed such that at least some of the previous word falls onto the line with the dots.

[image: Example of manual solution]
I think this could be accomplished by tricking latex into thinking all the text following \mydots is one word. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Not sure of what you want exactly ... may be `\dotfill\mbox{...}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

a bit of glue balancing....

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mydots{\futurelet\mytmp\xmydots}

\def\xmydots{\ifx\mytmp\textit
\expandafter\xxmydots
\else
\expandafter\xxxmydots
\fi}

\def\xxmydots#1#2{\xxxmydots\mbox{#1{#2}}}

\def\xxxmydots{\leavevmode
\unskip\nobreak\space
\null\nobreak\xleaders\hbox to 0.40em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill\kern0pt}
\textwidth7cm
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}\rightskip0pt plus.7\hsize
        \item First Line \mydots \textit{10 km}
        \item Second line \mydots \textit{20 meters}
        \item Another entry \mydots \textit{10 dollars}
        \item Some longer distance$^1$ \mydots \textit{20 goals}
        \item Time for parentheses (+1L) \mydots \textit{20 liters}
        \item Time for zero parenthesees \mydots \textit{20 liters}
        \item Time for a really lengthy sentence \mydots \textit{40 euros}
        \item Now-hyphened sentence \mydots \textit{10 doors}
        \item Now-hyphened but really long sentence \mydots \textit{20 points}
        \item another short \mydots \textit{5 verses}
        \item Last one for now$^1$ \mydots \textit{30 days}\\ \rule{0 pt}{0in}$^1$\textit{Sample footnote causing no known issue}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that  in "10 km" only the first character is in italic.

Comment: @ David, Im trying to make this work without requiring the following text to  be `\textit{}`. But I do not understand `\def\xxmydots#1#2{\xxxmydots\mbox{#1{#2}}}` Can you explain what is being passed as parameters?